# Neural networks converge after only several steps

Tags: neural-networks, convergence

I am working on a sequence classification problem and have a pretty large dataset (100k examples). The inputs are binary vectors of length 100 and the output is a binary yes/no vector. I have tried several different architectures including fully-connected feed-forward NN, CNN and RNN. The problem is that after choosing the appropriate learning rate and using the Adam optimizer all networks converge after only 10-20 steps (200 samples per step) to smth like 0.65 auc. Tuning parameters or switching architectures improves only convergence, but not the final score. Does it mean that my problem is not well-defined? Am I using wrong features? Is it the best result I can get with this dataset? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide any extra information on what your task is and  what the data set is composed of? (primarily what are the inputs and the targets)

Comment: The three questions you ask at the end are also what I would be asking, but it's hard to say if it's a problem that doesn't have results that are already published or well known. One thing to make sure of is that the answer is actually in the data. For example, an image has the answer 100% in the pixel data. When we look at the image we know what it is purely from the pixels and don't use any outside information to recognize it, so a NN can do the same. But if you asked it to output the name of who took the picture it would struggle.

Comment: Also to help rule out an error in your code, try using maybe 1k examples or even less to train on and try to overfit it and see if you still get stuck in the same spot. You should be able to get really high accuracy even if the answer to your problem isn't embedded in the data, as long as your code is right

Comment: @Frobot Thank you very much! Yes, it is not clear whether the data is sufficient to do the classification. I will try to overfit though.

Comment: @Frobot I was able to overfit, which means there is no error in the code.